# Is there an equivalent of `pip install -e` in R?

Tags: r, pip, r-package, package-development

From python `pip install -h`:

```
-e, --editable <path/url>   Install a project in editable mode (i.e. setuptools 
                            "develop mode") from a local project path or a VCS url.
```

Basically , if you `pip install -e <package_dir>`, pip will install a python package, and symlink to the package, instead of copying it's contents. This is very useful, because it means that you can edit the package, and the changes are available immediately, without having to re-install the package after every modification.

Is there an equivalent for R packages? This would be extremely useful for package development.

Comment: Is this a package that you are developing or you mean other's package?
In either way, you can edit and then use `devtools::load_all('path\to\package')`

Comment: @GGamba: True, I guess that's equivalent to a library call, for practical purposes. But it does mean that the actual code of scripts has to be changed, which is a bit annoying...

Comment: If the close-voter could comment on why this is not clear, I'm happy to clarify.

Comment: Devtools works like this in the sense that what I do is clone a package (or create my package) to a folder and then have that folder be a project. Then when editing use "build and load."

Comment: @Elin: What do you mean by "build and load"

Comment: That's an option on the build menu in RStudio.

Comment: Ah. I'm not using RStudio.